# mysql: expected time for a simple group by on a single table, 2M records, single user?

Tags: mysql, performance

related to [MySQL tuning (my.cnf) for very large tables and ad hoc queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39787/mysql-tuning-my-cnf-for-very-large-tables-and-ad-hoc-queries)

I have a really small table with 2M records, on a 32GB machine, running Windows 10 Pro with nothing serious running except MySql 5.7. I expected that simple group by on any *un-indexed* column would take seconds, as Mysql would cache the entire table. It takes about 3 minutes. Am I missing some important tuning tip? or are these the expected times?

the query

```
mysql> select specialty_code, count(*)
    -> from physicians
    -> group by specialty_code;
+----------------+----------+
| specialty_code | count(*) |
+----------------+----------+
| FM             |   199604 |
| GYN            |    14263 |
| OBG            |    78878 |
+----------------+----------+
3 rows in set (2 min 56.27 sec)
```

the table

```
mysql> describe physicians;
+-----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| physician_id          | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| practitioner_id       | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| state                 | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| specialty_code        | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| specialty_description | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CBSA                  | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.10 sec)    

mysql> show table status like '%physicians%';
+------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name       | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows    | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| physicians | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 1963005 |             66 |   130711552 |               0 |            0 |   2097152 |           NULL | 2016-01-04 08:41:30 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

sizing:

```
mysql> select count(*) from physicians;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1957997 |
+----------+
1 row in set (9.91 sec)
```

explain:

```
mysql> explain select specialty_code, count(*)
    -> from physicians
    -> group by specialty_code;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | physicians | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1963005 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

params I tuned:

```
join_buffer_size=2G 
tmp_table_size=5G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G
sort_buffer_size=2G
```

The table uses the default InnoDB engine.

NOTE: this is just a simplified symptom of my bigger problem: I have ~5-6 tables with a total volume of 10 GB. I expected MySql to swoosh all of them into the memory and answer any ad-hoc query within a minute or so... Should I index every column before filtering/grouping/joining on it?

Thanks and sorry if this is ranting. I'm just used to distributed databases crunching data in milliseconds for me :)

Comment: The `Using temporary` together with a `TEXT` column for grouping means on-disk (MyISAM) temporary table, so lot of disk IO. You might put the temp dir for those on some ram disk as a quick and dirty solution, but seeing the results only contains max 3 characters in the column, you should probably restructure the table a bit, use (VAR)CHAR(3), ENUM or maybe a lookup table (smallint foreign key) for that column. Check the other columns too if they need to be TEXT.

Comment: Revert the changes to `join_buffer_size` and `sort_buffer_size` - those are allocated per-thread (connected client) so can hurt performance badly and even crash/kill mysql because of not enough memory. Revert the `tmp_table_size` setting too, it can only work in combination with `max_heap_table_size` and only for [some tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) (and the TEXT column explicitly forces the on-disk table anyway)

Comment: thanks @jkavalik, about the buffers - I've checked and there's no swap happening, MySql is taking tops 20G out of my 30G with all those settings, so no worries there. I'm the only user connecting and there's only 1 session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> tmp_table_size=5G

No.  Go back to the default.  If multiple queries need tmp tables, you could run out of RAM.

Change the `TEXT` fields to reasonable-length `VARCHARs`.

The *first* table scan will do I/O to bring the table into RAM (if possible); subsequent references to the table will see the data cached.  Did you run the `GROUP BY` twice to see this effect?

Comment: Thanks @rick-james, about tmp_table_size - even if I can be absolutely sure that I'm the only one connecting to this db, and only one session would be active at any given moment? I checked and there's plenty of RAM left....

Comment: OK 5G is harmless today.  If, as the data and activity grows, you suddenly get a massive slowdown, reach for that setting.

Comment: @ihadanny Did you see an improvement on the second run? What happened? I'm also used to distributed datastores and have no idea what to expect from mysql

Comment: @RileyLark , I did see an improvement once I stopped using TEXT fields, which was just wrong. However, I was way off-mark with my lousy 32GB machine :) Turns out nowadays people use bigger beasts to host their data. See this thread with smart insights: https://www.kaggle.com/c/cervical-cancer-screening/forums/t/18693/being-smart-about-loading-data

Comment: (Re @RileyLark 's sampling)  If you are experimenting with algorithms, theories, etc, why not have 2 small tables with _random_ subsets of the data -- experiment with one table, test with the other, then finally check with the big table.