# Which database should I look at for analyzing ~30gb, 700M records dataset?

Tags: mysql, performance, sqlite, rdbms

I'm looking at analyzing a [kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/cervical-cancer-screening/data) which is pretty normalized, specifically joining, grouping, slicing and dicing the 3 tables `patients(2M) <-> diagnosis(700M) <-> doctors(2M)`.

I have 30GB RAM, 300GB SSD machine, so I'm able to analyze using a good old c program (I practically malloc and load everything to memory...), but I want to employ the power of ad-hoc SQL queries.

I tried different MySql, SQLLite and even mini-hadoop configurations, both on my machine and on google compute cloud and amazon EC (just to make sure that its not a config/env problem).

I can't find anything that will give me results in less than a couple of minutes to any ad-hoc query.. and if I didn't go thru the hassle of building indexes ad-hoc performance was atrocious (hours or so).

*Am I missing something obvious?* If its possible for my c program to fit everything in memory and do crude analysis, isn't there a database which loads everything to the buffer cache and gives lightning-fast performance for all the wonderful SQL analytics?

I know this might some a bit naive, but please go easy on me - I'm used to huge Teradata/Hadoop clusters doing heavylifting of many TB of data in very good timings, so I expected this to be very easy to handle...

Comment: Considering your related question ([mysql: expected time for a simple group by on a single table, 2M records, single user?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125106/mysql-expected-time-for-a-simple-group-by-on-a-single-table-2m-records-single)), your main problem is the design. `Text` column to store a few bytes status? It should be `TINYINT`. No indexes at all and you expect miracles? Wow, speechless.

Comment: If your queries consist of aggregate functions and group by's then I suggest you use some kind of cube tool instead

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment...)

MySQL...

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';` -- the main configuraton is the cache allocation.  But it depends on which Engine you are using and how much RAM you have.

> pretty normalized, specifically joining, grouping, slicing and dicing the 3 tables

Sorry, but we need to check the details.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, some slow queries plus their `EXPLAINs`.

Are you CPU-bound?  Then the queries and/or indexes need attending to.

Are you I/O-bound?  Then probably indexes.

**Edit 1**

Glancing at the "schema", I see something naughty:  `diagnosis_code` is `NUMBER` in one table and `VARCHAR(30)` in another.  This makes it impossible to use an index when `JOINing`.

So, I repeat, let's see the MySQL version of `CREATE TABLE` and the queries.